# How to count plot column value with interval in matplotlib/seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

I have a column of value and I have to plot the value like <0.99,1 to 1.99,2 to 3.99 and 4>
I tried the below code

```
data = pd.cut(TPA_Data_Details['cokumn name'], bins=[-np.inf,0.99,1,1.99,2,3.99,4,np.inf])
plt.figure(figsize=(17,15))
sns.countplot(data)
```

but it is giving the output like this [image]

how to make the bar from (-inf,0.99),(1,1.99),(2,3.99) and (4,inf)?

Comment: What should happen to the value 0.995? Why don't you want to exclude these values from analysis?

Comment: all the value equal to or less than 0.99 will be shown as one bar in the plot

Comment: In your range definition, you exclude the range (0.99, 1). This is what I am pointing out. (And it was supposed to be "Why do you want...", meh). Are you sure, you are not just looking for `bins=[-np.inf,1,2,4,np.inf])`?

Comment: Thank you. It works but not as I am wanting.

Comment: Care to explain why you want to exclude certain values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to exclude parts of the range, then you have to organize the histogram yourself:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#generate sample data
np.random.seed(123)
n=100
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.random(n)*50 - 5})

#count the numbers per bin
vals, bins = np.histogram(df["A"], bins=[-np.inf,0.99,1,1.99,2,3.99,4,np.inf])

#plot and label only every other bar
plt.bar([f"[{i}, {j})" for i, j in zip(bins[::2], bins[1::2])], vals[::2])
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

The last bin actually includes `np.inf` but you will manage to change the x-label to `[4.0, inf]`.